# Помощь в подключении SDL к проекту Win 32 VS 2012

Tags: sdl, visual-studio

Ранее работал в SDL 1.2, всё прошло без происшествий. Но вот в очередной проект решил интегрировать SDL 2.0 после не долгой борьбы, я упёрся в ошибку

"**error LNK1107: недопустимый или поврежденный файл: не удается прочитать по location**"

На MSDN глянул что может быть проблема из-за того что либа компилировалась с флагом **/NOASSEMBLY** и я скачал исходники, перекомпилировал и.. только location в ошибке сменился :) Ругается на SDL2.dll

На ввод компоновщику даю следующее

- SDL\x64\SDL2.lib
- SDL\x64\SDL2main.lib
- SDL\x64\SDL2.dll

Кто сталкивался, как бороться?

Comment: попробуйте "вручную" удалить файлы после компиляции и пресобрать проэкт заново мне наиногда помогало.

Comment: Вряд ли поможет, такая ошибка была сначала с консольным приложением, я погрешил на это и по этому создал новый и перенёс исходники туда, проблема не исчезла.

Comment: я пробовал с SDL писать, скачал с их сайта dll lib h файлы, положил все в указанные директории. подключал lib файлы с помощью директивы препроцессора pragma. Настройки проэкта были по умолчанию - все работало без проблем

Comment: Со старой версией тоже проблем не было. .lib нормально "подсосались" а вот с .dll проблема.

Comment: попробуйте в интернете поискать ту же версию dll со стороннего сайта. обычно при неправильной версии dll пишет что не может нужную точку входа найти

Comment: Так, убрал и настройки линковщика .dll и подключил с помощью 
#pragma comment(lib,"SDL\\x64\\SDL2.lib")
Теперь ошибка которая была до того как я пытался подключить .dll, мне кажется я с подключением что то не то сделал.  
error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "SDL_main"

Comment: мне кажется вы зря путь указываете SDL\x64\ попробуйте просто SDL2.lib, а либ файлы положить прямо в каталог с либами

Comment: Пробовал после того как в буржуйском интернете погуглил, не спасает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройках проекта выбираем. 
**Компоновщик - Общие - Дополнительные каталоги библиотек** = указываем путь до папки где лежат lib файлы    
**Компоновщик - Ввод - Дополнительные зависимости** = прописываем библиотеки которые надо подключить без указания пути (к примеру "SDL2.lib" "SDL2main.lib") без кавычек.

UPD. Так же хочу сказать что надо проект сразу строить в Release версию, а не Debug. 
UPD2. Так же вы указываете в библиотеках DLL файл, а его не нужно указывать.

Comment: Стоит Release и x64. Если указать только либы то:

error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "SDL_main"

Почитаю доки.

Comment: так SDLmain.lib вроде файл называется, а не SDL_main.lib         
так же вроде библиотеки SDL не поддерживают x64 ((

Comment: Заменил 
void main();
на 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);

Всё построилось нормально, всем спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: Во второй версии либы вероятней всего SDL_main макросом переопределяется на пользовательскую функцию.

Comment: Ну не знаю, я скачал SDL2.0 и там файл SDLmain.lib без подчеркивания. 
С подчеркиванием это дополнительные библиотеки у SDL типа image ttf mixer.